# How to call the outcome of a cooking recipe, in quantitative terms

Tags: terminology

Talking about cooking recipes, how do you call "the amount of it that the recipe produces", the recipe outcome in quantitative terms?

I'm looking for the more professional term, the one used by professional cooks.

I think it's "this recipe yields 12 servings" or "... yields 4 Kg."
On the other hand, some recipes appear saying "... for 12 servings."

Note: cross-posted in Seasoned Advice, the cooks' place.

Comment: 'will serve 12'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes; or just “Serves 12”.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the served or servings word. My wife (a great cook) says it's the way.

Comment: But it appears questioned as the serving size is not defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The is the recipe's **yield**. Here is a reference in a culinary textbook, [Basic Kitchen and Food Service Management](https://opentextbc.ca/basickitchenandfoodservicemanagement/chapter/yield-testing/):

> ***Yield*** in culinary terms refers to how much you will have of a finished or processed product. Professional recipes should always state a yield; for example, a tomato soup recipe may yield 15 L, and a muffin recipe may yield 24 muffins. Yield can also refer to the amount of usable product after it has been processed (peeled, cooked, butchered, etc.)